# Global variables in CodeIgniter view

Tags: codeigniter, global-variables

I am following [the Nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/) to implement Basecamp-style subdomains with CodeIgniter.

Based on the calling subdomain, the subdomain table in the database returns an extension corresponding to that subdomain.  So say for `stackoverflow.mywebsite.com`, it will return the extension `sf`, and the image folder and CSS file used all over the website will change on the basis of this extension; for example, `images_sf`, `style_sf.css`, etc.

Now, what is the best way to fetch this extension anywhere in M, V, or C ?

Options:

1. Cookies
2. Dynamically setting CI config variable
3. Set a variable for this in `MY_Controller` and access that variable via `$this->` anywhere.
4. Send that variable from each controller to models, helpers, views or libraries.

Did I miss any other options?  Also, which one will be best assuming this will be heavily used all over the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would create a base controller for each site that you extend, and just use `$this->load->vars($data);` to load the information you need globally set.

In the constructor of your specific base Controller just load the data into the views globally like this.

```
$data->some_var = "some value";
$this->load->vars($data);
```

And then in all your views loaded by this controller (or base controller) you can utilize the variable `$some_var` directly in the view.

Comment: isn't setting them via php DEFINE is best way ? I am sure once set they will never change during the script execution.

Comment: Your question might be a bit misleading because in the title you ask about CodeIgniter views, but in the question you ask about loading the information into all of the M, V, and C.  This method will load these variables globally into the views loaded by this controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably option 3, to put it in the constructor of your base contoller, probably MY_controller or whatever you are extending Controller (now CI_Controller with the CI2.0 official release)

However if all you're doing is getting an extension, there might not be a reason to have a database table, since you could just keep it in a config file

I'd do something like this... in MY_Controller.php (This is CI 2.0 syntax)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct()
      {
           parent::__construct();

           $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);  
           $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];  

           $this->load->config('sub_prefix');
           $pre_arr = $this->config->item('prefixes');

           /* Check to make sure the subdomain name is in the config array */
           $this->prefix = isset($pre_arr[$subdomain_name]) ? $pre_arr[$subdomain_name] : '';
      }
```

Then in the config file (sub_prefix.php)

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

    $config['prefixes'] = array('subdomain1' => 'sub1', 
                                'stackoverflow' => 'sf');
```

That way you don't have to run an extra query everytime the page loads for something that is relatively static...if you got to the point where there would be a lot more information you would need other than a prefix, then it would make sense to do it with the database

You can now just use $this->prefix in any of the views, controllers, or models you will be using... the best way to do it for something that is heavily use all over your application.

Comment: I have to fetch it from db as there many be 1000s of subdomains using the app. so hardcoding them in config may not be best... may be setting config item dynamically ? or set using php define ?