# Overwriting CI_Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I've overwritten my CI_Controller so I can do a user check specific for each controller, for example, the Guest_Controller is accessible by everyone, User_Controller is only for logged in users.

This all works fine, however I've only overwritten the output here

```
class Guest_Controller extends CI_Controller
{  
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _output($content)
    {
        // Load the base template with output content available as $content
        $data['content'] = &$content;       
        echo($this->load->view('templates/html_guest', $data, true));
    }
}

class Homepage extends Guest_Controller {
    public function __contruct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Homagepage',
            'page_title' => 'Homepage',
            'body_classes' => 'home'
        );
        $this->parser->parse('homepage', $data);
    }
}
```

In my `$data` you can see I have `body_classes`, I use this so I can give each page an individual class, based on it's own needs.
Now, what would be the best way of adding default `body_classes` in my `Guest_Controller`?

If the `body_class` is only **home**, how can I add some default ones to it?

Edit: So I'm looking for a way to easily add body classes, while still having some defaults ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Guest_Controller extends CI_Controller
{  
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _output($content)
    {
        // Load the base template with output content available as $content
        $data['content'] = &$content;       
        echo($this->load->view('templates/html_guest', $data, true));
    }

    //specify default values with $page_info
    protected function get_page_info($page_info)
    {
         $data = array(
            'title' => 'default',
            'page_title' => 'default',
            'body_classes' => 'default'
         );

         foreach ($page_info as $key => $value) 
             $data[$key] = $value;    

         return $data;        
    } 

}

class Homepage extends Guest_Controller {
    public function __contruct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Homagepage',
            'page_title' => 'Homepage',
        );
        $this->parser->parse('homepage', $this->get_page_info($data));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed an option, although I was hoping to still keep using $this->parser->parse('homepage', $data); and have something in my Guest_Controller overwrite this

Comment: Maybe you can use global view variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835840/global-variables-in-codeigniter-view